# Observing changes in Room Database table using ItemKeyedDataSource

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have implemented class which extends [**ItemKeyedDataSource**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/ItemKeyedDataSource.html) and provides paging data from room database's data access object (DAO). My DAO's query methods pass lists of data objects (not wrapped by `LiveData`) to `DataSource` callbacks.

What is the recommended way to invalidate `DataSource` after changes occur in it's wrapped database table, for example if changes come from background Service? How automatic data invalidation is implemented in `DataSource.Factory<Integer, T>` return parameter that DAOs can generate?

Comment: as you said DAOs can generate `DataSource.Factory`, so why do you need to create your own `ItemKeyedDataSource` implementation?

Comment: Because DAOs can generate only PositionalDataSource which does not suit my needs.

Comment: see `android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker
` and how it is used by `LimitOffsetDataSource` and `RoomDatabase`

Comment: @pskink Yes, thank you! `InvalidationTracker` is exactly what I was looking for. You can post answer to my question if you wish, then I will accept it or I may answer it my self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatic `DataSource` invalidation can be implemented by hooking `InvalidationTracker.Observer` to `InvalidationTracker`. 
You can get `InvalidationTracker` instance from [getInvalidationTracker()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.html#getInvalidationTracker()).

I implemented my `InvalidationTracker.Observer` like this:

```
public class DataSourceTableObserver extends InvalidationTracker.Observer {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSourceTableObserver(@NonNull String tableName) {
        super(tableName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
       if (dataSource != null) dataSource.invalidate();
    }

    public void setCurrentDataSource(DataSource source) {
        dataSource = source;
    }

}
```

And I'm using it in my inner `DataSource.Factory` class like this:

```
public static class Factory implements DataSource.Factory<TvProgram, TvProgram> {

    private Context appContext;
    private DataSourceTableObserver observer;
    private InvalidationTracker tracker;
    private int channelId;

    public Factory(Context context, int channelId) {
        appContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        observer = new DataSourceTableObserver(AppDatabase.PROGRAMS_TABLE);
        tracker = AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext).getInvalidationTracker();
        tracker.addObserver(observer);

        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource<TvProgram, TvProgram> create() {
        EpgDataSource epgDataSource = new EpgDataSource(appContext, channelId);
        observer.setCurrentDataSource(epgDataSource);
        return epgDataSource;
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        tracker.removeObserver(observer);
        observer = null;
    }

}
```

When `DataSourceTableObserver` invalidates `DataSource`, it's `Factory` inner class creates new `DataSource` instance with newest data.

Comment: Can you please look into my post and advise how I can implement over here in observing the Room table.                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830522/real-time-data-from-sqlite-database-through-room-outside-activity-fragment-follo?noredirect=1#comment94581735_53830522