# Real Time Data from Sqlite database through Room outside Activity/Fragment following MVVM Model

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I am following the MVVM Model. I would like to have Real-time data from SQLite database through Room (Results shall available as soon as data changes in Database). With LiveData, we can get results in Activity/Fragment. Callback also won't good on this type of requirement since data should be pushed from the database. Is there any way I can get in any class outside of activity/fragment?.

Thanx in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Putting sample code for better understanding..Is there a way to observe Room database Table so that we always have latest data from table?

```
  Filter filter =  mCustomerFilterDao.fetchcustomerSettings(settings);
  // Want to add observe for filter table so that we have latest customer 
  //settings. This is my Query.
  List<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<>();

 for(Book book:bookrecords)
 {
   if(book.status == filter.status)
     {booklist.add(book);}
  }
```

Comment: see `android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker` API documentation

Comment: My apology unable to understand so as to apply them. May I request to provide some more info as to how should I implement it. Thanks in advance

Comment: InvalidationTracker.Observer(String[] tables) : Lets say table name is books. Where I need to define this method? Is it in Dao? and how to use it?

Comment: Ya read this line many times but dint understand where should I put addObserver method. Currently using observe in activity for observing LiveData only. Request you to guide how to implement it.

Comment: I want to put in doInBackground of Asynch function for retrieving latest information in table and then apply those parameters for filtering of records. Getting error "Cannot resolved Method". Missing the right way of putting it. Rgds

Comment: Asking customer to put their filter parameters and saving it in Room database. Retrieving this info from this table so that same can be applied on book list to filter result. observe shall help me to get changes added in filter so as to reflect latest parameters for filtering. Hope it is clear. Thanx

Comment: no, its not - actually i have no idea what you are trying to do - so you will have to wait for someone else...

Comment: I am just taking customer input for filtering book record. Saving this filter parameter in Room database and retrieving it and applying to book list so as to filter books based on user requirement.                                                           Can you suggest me how to implement addobserver. Will appreciate if you can put some code for it so that I can understand how to apply it.

Comment: @pskink Invalidation Tracker gives list of tables that get updated by query. It does not tell why and  what has changed. I am looking to get changed data from table. Anybody can provide their suggestion please.

Comment: this is not possible